# Wireguard: Operation not permiited?

Tags: linux, vpn, modprobe

I installed wireguard but I am not able to load the module with modprobe.
When I run the command I get the following error:

```
modprobe wireguard
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wireguard': Operation not permitted
```

Tried out with insmod as well:

```
insmod /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/kernel-5.3.0-42-generic-x86_64/module/wireguard.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/kernel-5.3.0-42-generic-x86_64/module/wireguard.ko: Operation not permitted
```

The same error persists. Any suggestions how to solve this?

If Secure Boot was enabled, it would block the kernel module from loading as it is unsigned. so I ran these commands to resolve that:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo x > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

But still the same error..

Comment: Running as `root` to do the `insmod`? Normally only root can edit the kernel by inserting or removing modules.

Comment: yes i am running as a root

Comment: I went to the bios settings and disabled the secureboot there. Now it works

Comment: Congratulations on solving the problem yourself. You may want to post this as an answer to your own questions, so that others facing a similar problem can profit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Go the bios setting and disable secureboot